# Permutation feature importance to produce particular value

Tags: python, r, statistics, permutation

Using observations `X` I'm estimating the differential entropy of two groups, group1 and group2 with i samples each. I calculated the differential entropy between group 1 and group 2 to be statistically significant.
Now, I'm trying to determine what observations are greatly contributing to the difference in differential entropy between the two groups. What I'm currently doing is removing n sampled observations from `X` for each sample within each groups and recalculating the differential entropy to identify what observation(s) are contributing the most. If we remove n random observations from group 1 and the differential entropy is similar to group 2, then we have identified important features that can be used for downstream analysis. However, it's highly inefficient and I'm unsure how to calculate a p-value for this.

`scikitlearn` has a function called `permutation_importance` which does something similar but requires a model. Is there another implementation to identify important features that are contributing to a particular outcome but doesn't require a fitted model?
Python, R, or bash are all fine.
Thanks!

Comment: There is a package in `R` called `vegan` that may be useful. There is section called “Significance Test” here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vignettes/intro-vegan.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do a filter based on the variance of the features also... usually features that have low variance are not very incisive and in this way you no longer think about the individual records but about the feature in a whole. sklear have this method https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html removes all low variance features so you could code a thing to check when dropping features base on incresing variance threshold the differential entropy is same for both classes...